# Magento 2.2.3 - Add custom required validation for company

Tags: magento2, checkout, magento2.2, attributes, validation

I want to add validation only for billing address on the checkout page.

By default in the backend, the `company` name is optional.

[image]

But if when I go to the checkout page and click on the `Place Order` button then I want to add require field validation for `company` field.

[image]

In which company name is not available so I just want to trigger that required.

Does have any idea about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

> Add di.xml in your module

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>                                                  
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor" type="vendor\module\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor" />
```

> Create a LayoutProcessor.php in this path vendor\module\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor.php

Copy the file from

> Vendor/magento/module-checkout/Block/Checkout/LayoutProcessor.php

To

> app/code/vendor/module/Block/Checkout/LayoutProcessor.php

and change the below params to make the company as required field

```
 'company' => [
                            'validation' => [
                                'required-entry' => true,
                                'min_text_length' => 0,
                            ],
                        ],
```

Existing Billing Address of company field validation.

> Add this file in app/code/vendor/module/etc/di.xml

add the following code,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>                                           
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Magento\Checkout\Model\PaymentInformationManagement" type="Vendor\Module\Model\PaymentInformationManagement" />
```

> Add the file in app/code/Vendor\Module\Model\PaymentInformationManagement.php

add the following code to validate empty company in billing address is not allowed.

```
<?php                                                         
 namespace Vendor\Module\Model;                                     
 use Magento\Framework\Exception\CouldNotSaveException;           
 class PaymentInformationManagement extends \Magento\Checkout\Model\PaymentInformationManagement                      
 {
public function savePaymentInformationAndPlaceOrder(
    $cartId,
    \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\PaymentInterface $paymentMethod,
    \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface $billingAddress = null
) {
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $cart = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart');
    $billingAddress = $cart->getQuote()->getBillingAddress();

    if (!$billingAddress->getCompany()) {
        throw new CouldNotSaveException(__('Company should not be empty in billing address'));
        return false;
    } else {
        $this->savePaymentInformation($cartId, $paymentMethod, $billingAddress);
        try {
            $orderId = $this->cartManagement->placeOrder($cartId);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            throw new CouldNotSaveException(
                __('An error occurred on the server. Please try to place the order again.'),
                $e
        );
        }
        return $orderId;
    }
}}
```

Hope this helps.
Peace :)

Comment: I have already check but it's not working for an existing customer billing address.

Comment: Both are different forms the above example will work only on checkout billing address. You want for an existing customer ?

Comment: yes. I want only for existing billing address.

Comment: Give me some time, I'll figure out and let you know

Comment: Please check I have updated question.

Comment: It's actually out of box, since magento have  place order button only to place order and it's not for the purpose for validating. Hence you can add validation at shipping level so it restrict there itself and if not then you can add place order before event observer to get it validate. That's how it would work out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89875/discussion-between-emipro-technologies-pvt-ltd-and-g-prathap).

Comment: @EmiproTechnologiesPvt.Ltd. Updated the answer as per you requirement. Kindly check it and let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you just update it to **Required** using the same Dropdown?

[image]

Comment: No. Because we only require it to in billing address only.