# How to set require field to company in billing address in magento2?

Tags: magento2, validation, billing-address

How to set require the field to a company in billing address in magento2?

Comment: This answer will help you out https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/262239/magento-2-2-3-add-custom-required-validation-for-company/262244#262244

Comment: Thanks, It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You should as well add it in your attribute on the server side.

If you're using Magento Entreprise Edition, you can simply edit the company attribute through back end, and set it to "required".

If you're working with a Community Edition, you'll have to manually change this value with SQL. It's in **eav_attribute** table, the attribute_code is company and you just need to set **is_required** to 1.

Comment: Check this link:https://screencast.com/t/N2FNlRisru

I want like this on the payment page.

Comment: Try the solution once, I think, it will do the same.